# pdfx: incomplete CIDset in some fonts

Tags: luatex, pdf, pdf-a, pdfx

I try to compile a document as pdf/x and pdf/a with `pdfx` under `LuaLaTeX`, and I am already quite successful. One thing still poses problems though: With some fonts I get the following error if I check the resulting pdf/a file with Acrobat: "CIDset in subset font is incomplete (font contains glyphs that are not listed)" (VeraPDF gives the same error, so the issue seems to be real).

Here's a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{Test}
      \Author{Simon Spiegel}
      \Language{de-DE}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass
{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
[Ligatures={TeX,Common},
Extension = .ttf,
]
\usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I realise that not everyone will be able to compile this MWE due to the proprietary font, but since the problem only occurs with specific fonts, I had to use this example.

The `pdfx` manual mentions this error, but only in relation to `XeLaTeX`. According to the manual, it should not occur with `LuaLaTeX`.

From what I understand, this seems to be at least to some degree a problem of this specific font, but since I am relying on it, I am looking for a way to fix it.

**EDIT**

Here's a new MWE with a bunch of fonts which are hopefully more common (the paths have to be adapted of course).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{Test}
      \Author{Simon Spiegel}
      \Language{de-DE}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass
{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
[Ligatures={TeX,Common},
Extension = .ttf,
]

\newfontfamily\fontone{Verdana}
[Ligatures={TeX,Common},
Extension = .ttf,
]
\newfontfamily\fonttwo{Cambria}
[Ligatures={TeX,Common},
Extension = .ttf,
Path = {/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/C/Cambria/}
]
\usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Test

\fontone
Test

\fonttwo
Test
\end{document}
```

All these fonts give me the same error. I wonder if this only happens with .ttf OpenType fonts.

Comment: I don't have the font, so I can't test.

Comment: I added additional fonts. I hope one works for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the variable `omitcidset` to 1 (thanks to Hans Hagen ...):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
\pdfvariable omitcidset=1
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

(probably pdfx should do it, so better inform the maintainer)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Strange that this is not automatically set with the pdf/a setting of `pdfx`.

Comment: Imho the maintainer is mostly working with pdftex - and I had to ask too ;-) (it is documented, but one tends to skim over such stuff).

Comment: Is it documented in the `pdfx` manual? I only see this problem mentioned in relation to `XeLaTeX` and the `omitcidset` isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: It is documented in the luatex manual.

Comment: Ah, ok. Should probably also be included in `pdfx`.

Comment: Strange: I do not get this error in MikTeX without `omitcidset`. When I set it to `1` I get a validation error. When I set it to `0` everything is fine again.

Comment: After this I get another error... `CIDset in subset font missing`