# PDF/A-1u validation failure due to incorrect "CIDSet stream" from CJK fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, cjk, pdf-a

This document...

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=zh-Hans]{chineseS}
\babelfont[chineseS]{rm}{AR PL UMing CN}
\begin{document}
what \foreignlanguage{chineseS}{什么什么} what
\end{document}
```

... compiled with `lualatex`, produces a PDF that fails PDF/A validation (veraPDF v1.16.1) with an error that I have no idea how to resolve:

> clause 6.2.11.4 test 4: If the FontDescriptor dictionary of an embedded CID font contains a CIDSet stream,
> then it shall identify all CIDs which are present in the font program, regardless
> of whether a CID in the font is referenced or used by the PDF or not.

veraPDF also tells me that the offending font is AR PL UMing CN.  I tried replacing it with each other CJK font I have, with the same result.

Is this a problem with the fonts, or a problem with TeX itself, or what? Is there anything I can do about it?

Note: The full document from which this is cut down, is primarily written in English but contains many short phrases in both Simplified and Traditional Chinese script.  There is also one paragraph-length quotation in Japanese which requires both kanji and kana.  So I need fonts that, taken together, can handle all three.

Comment: try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474336/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That worked, make it an answer?