# Embed Arial font in a PDF/A-friendly way

Tags: luatex, fontspec, overleaf, embedding, pdf-a

Due to external requirements, I have to use Arial and Arial Bold in certain parts of my LaTeX document. At the same time, the document has to meet the PDF/A-2 standard. I have tried several ways to add Arial and it does work, but when checking for PDF/A-2 compliance with [veraPDF](https://verapdf.org/) I always get the same result.

```
$ verapdf -v -x mydocument.pdf --flavor 2b
...Irrelevant stuff...
    <validationReport profileName="PDF/A-2B validation profile" statement="PDF file is not compliant with Validation Profile requirements." isCompliant="false">
        <details passedRules="121" failedRules="1" passedChecks="649" failedChecks="1">
          <rule specification="ISO 19005-2:2011" clause="6.2.11.4" testNumber="4" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
            <description>If the FontDescriptor dictionary of an embedded CID font contains a CIDSet stream, then it shall identify all CIDs which are present in the font program,
            regardless of whether a CID in the font is referenced or used by the PDF or not.</description>
            <object>PDCIDFont</object>
            <test>fontFile_size == 0 || fontName.search(/[A-Z]{6}\+/) != 0 || CIDSet_size == 0 || cidSetListsAllGlyphs == true</test>
            <check status="failed">
              <context>root/document[0]/pages[0](14 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](16 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[11]/font[0](XBXSEC+ArialMT)/DescendantFonts[0](XBXSEC+ArialMT)</context>
            </check>
          </rule>
        </details>
      </validationReport>
...More irrelevant stuff...
```

Running `pdffonts` on the file results in the following output

```
$ pdffonts mydocument.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
OLAZTU+LMRoman12-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     18  0
XBXSEC+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     17  0
```

I am trying to make sense of the error message, but without much success. I was able to reduce it to the following minimal working example:

```latex
% This is just to silence a warning that I get:
%   "Writing or overwriting file `./output.xmpdata'".
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{latex}{Writing or overwriting file `}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{The title of the document}
\Author{Firstname Lastname}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a-2b, mathxmp]{pdfx}[2018/12/22]
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\Arial}{Arial}[Extension = .ttf, UprightFont = *]

\begin{document}
\Arial Whatever
\end{document}
```

I am using [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com) with LuaLaTeX. Apart from the `main.tex` file, I have a file called `Arial.ttf`, which contains the TrueType font.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `\pdfvariable omitcidset=1`, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474336/2388

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you @UlrikeFischer!