Creating standards compliant PDF-A with lualatex and cmyk colors
I'm trying to create a PDF-A file which passes verapdf validation.
But as soon as I add a cmyk color it fails.
MWE:
\DocumentMetadata{
  pdfstandard=A-4F,
  pdfversion=2.0,
  colorprofiles = {A = sRGB.icc, X = FOGRA39L_coated.icc},
  lang=de,
}
%
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
%
\definecolor{bpblue}{cmyk}{0.50,0.15,0.0,0.0}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474336
\pdfvariable omitcidset=1

\begin{document}

\textcolor{bpblue}{1}

\end{document}

I get from verapdf
Specification: ISO 19005-4:2020, Clause: 6.2.4.3, Test number: 3    
DeviceCMYK shall only be used if a device independent DefaultCMYK colour space has been set when the DeviceCMYK colour space is used or if the current transparency blending space, when the DeviceCMYK colour space is used, is a device independent CMYK-based colour space or the current PDF/A OutputIntent, when the DeviceCMYK colour space is used, contains a 'CMYK' destination profile

I'm using a TL 2024 updated last friday. I found some workarounds using older approaches (hyperxmp, Creating a PDF/A, PDF/X and PDF/UA multistandard compliant thesis or paper) but these don't work together with DocumentMetadata.

well pdf/A doesn't like it if you use both cmyk + rgb. You will have to decide which one you want to use. If you want cmyk you need to load a cmyk colorprofile and not sRGB.

Unrelated but the omitcid setting should not be necessary anymore.

Thanks, using
  colorprofiles = {A = FOGRA39L_coated.icc, X = FOGRA39L_coated.icc},


did indeed do the trick.

I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.
